# Where is the following function defined in the android source?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I found the following code in frameworks/base/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/IPhoneSubInfo.aidl

```
 /**
 * Retrieves the serial number of the ICC, if applicable.
 */
String getIccSerialNumber();
```

but I cannot grep the function getIccSerialNumber(), does anyone know where it is defined in source?

I tried with search on [Cyanogenmod's repository on github](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=getIccSerialNumber&type=Code) but no luck.

Comment: use http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/

Answer (score 0):

That function isn't actually a function that should be implemented anywhere by default. It's an AIDL method, if you don't know what that is check this out: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

Basically, you can understand it as an interface. Because it is an interface, there may not be any implementation provided in the Android project.